# Environment.CurrentDirectory giving program files path

Tags: vb.net

I would like to get path of my current running project and then go one folder up then being there go to MyFile.cfg. I tried to get that path using:

```
Dim currentprojectPath= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

unfortunetly i get strange path:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
```

Solution tree:

```
Configs (folder) 
    ConfigX (folder)
        MyFile.cfg            --> file i want to read path of

UnitTestProject (folder)      --> running project folder
```

Comment: How about AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ?

Comment: Thanks that works !